# openerp mobile application

Tags: python, mobile, odoo

Trying out the openERP 6.1 built in mobile application built with jquery mobile.
i have my own module "school.student", when i click on students i see the students tree, when i click on any specific student i get the error

```
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/fields.py", line 551, in get
    ids2 = obj.pool.get(self._obj).search(cr, user, 
                           self._domain + [(self._fields_id, 'in', ids)], 
                           limit=self._limit, context=context)
```

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'search'` 
as if it's not fetching that the object in question here is `school.student`

There is no similar error via web or gtk clients, only the new mobile client.
I dont get such an error when accessing any other object such as school.course or even `school.course.subjects`. just that one form view for school.student that doesnt open. any ideas on why this is happening?

EDIT: Traceback

`2012-09-07 13:57:47,199 17516 INFO ? werkzeug: 192.168.100.106 - - [07/Sep/2012 13:57:47] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -`
`> /opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/fields.py(554)get()`
`-> for r in obj.pool.get(self._obj)._read_flat(cr, user, ids2, [self._fields_id], context=context, load='_classic_write'):`
`(Pdb) ids2`
`[]`
`(Pdb) c`
`> /opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/fields.py(554)get()`
`-> for r in obj.pool.get(self._obj)._read_flat(cr, user, ids2, [self._fields_id], context=context, load='_classic_write'):`
`(Pdb) ids2`
`[]`
`(Pdb) c`
`> /opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/fields.py(554)get()`
`-> for r in obj.pool.get(self._obj)._read_flat(cr, user, ids2, [self._fields_id], context=context, load='_classic_write'):`
`(Pdb) ids2`
`[]`
`(Pdb) c`
`2012-09-07 13:58:03,198 17516 ERROR ? openerp.osv.osv: Uncaught exception`
`Traceback (most recent call last):`
`File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 121, in wrapper`
`return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)`
`File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 176, in execute`
`res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)`
`File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 164, in execute_cr`
`return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)`
`File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 3381, in read`
`result = self._read_flat(cr, user, select, fields, context, load)`
`File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 3504, in _read_flat`
`res2 = self._columns[f].get(cr, self, ids, f, user, context=context, values=res)`
`File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/fields.py", line 552, in get`
`ids2 = obj.pool.get(self._obj).search(cr, user, self._domain + [(self._fields_id, 'in', ids)], limit=self._limit, context=context)`
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'search'`
`2012-09-07 13:58:03,202 17516 ERROR ? openerp.netsvc: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'search'`
`2012-09-07 13:58:03,208 17516 INFO ? werkzeug: 192.168.100.106 - - [07/Sep/2012 13:58:03] "POST /web/dataset/search_read HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

Comment: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'search' means that its not finding your class in pool.get(self._obj)

what is your school.student code? are you sure you are including it in the _init_.py and have a _name = 'school.student' in your class?

Comment: @Timothy: yes i realize what that means. the code is rather long and there is a _name= 'school.student' and it's included in the init.py. as i said, the form opens fine in both the web client and gtk client. the error mentioned above only appears for the student form from the MOBILE client

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `self._obj` returns the values which is no in `pool` so when you try to get the object from the `pool` with the `get` method its try to find the key from the `dict` but as that key is not exist in `pool` it return the `None`.

If this will not get the error in GTK or WEB then please try to display `self._obj` in all client.

Comment: Thanks for the question improvement Lafada. I don't understand the last sentence you wrote: "If this will not get the error in GTK or WEB then please try to display self._obj in all client.". Can you please elaborate?

Comment: If you have a server access then please check what is the value of `self._obj` for each client. It may be possible that value will be change or `pool` may not contains that object.

Comment: I set a pdb trace after `ids2 = obj.pool.get(self._obj).search(cr, user, self._domain + [(self._fields_id, 'in', ids)], limit=self._limit, context=context)`and printed **self._obj** which came out on the 3 clients as `ir.actions.act_window.view`. also, `ids2` on all 3 clients also was `[]`. does that tell you anything Lafada? by the way, `ids2` also returned `[]` for some of the base components like Purchase/Address Book/Suppliers, and returned a normal dict for most others.

Comment: For the mobile client please check again. Because if it returns `ids2` as `[]` then there must be no error. As you told that error is shown `None type object has no attribute search` means it `obj.pool.get(self._obj)` return `None`. Also provide the full traceback so get some more idea. Just update your answer with full traceback.

Comment: I rechecked with the mobile client and `ids2` is always coming off as `[]`. i edited my answer with the traceback. is this the full traceback or do u mean the entire log? no errors or warning were shown before.

Comment: `ids2` is `[]` because you may be declare it as `ids2 = []` that's why its display the values. But its not executing statement `ids2 = obj.pool.get(self._obj).search(cr, user, self._domain + [(self._fields_id, 'in', ids)], limit=self._limit, context=context)` and set the value to `ids2`. As I mention earlier the problem is `self._obj` is not available in pool. Just try to print `self._obj in self.pool` and check the result you get `True` or `False` ?

Comment: self._obj was indeed false lafada, it returned an object that was not defined. one of the fields of the main class (student) was a one2many field to a deleted class. I dont know how i missed it, thanks very much for your help!

Comment: `False` means that class is not exist in the pool. Please check the same output in GTK and WEB client.

Comment: Lafada i told you, it turned out that self._obj using the mobile client was referencing an object of an undefined class in the py file through a declared one2many field. i commented the corresponding erroneous field in school.student and now it loads fine. Thanks again.